# Change NodePort to 80 in baremetal

Tags: kubernetes

If i use node port in `yml` file it give a port more than 30000
but  when my user want to use it they do not want to remember that port and want to use 80. my `kubernetes` cluster is on `baremetal`.
How can i solve that?

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes doesn't allow you to expose low ports via the Node Port service type by design. The idea is that there is a significant chance of a port conflict if users are allowed to set low port numbers for their Node Port services.

If you really want to use port 80, you're going to have to either use a Load Balancer service type, or route your traffic through an Ingress. If you were on a cloud service, then either option would be fairly straight forward. However, since you're on bare metal, both options are going to be very involved. You're going to have to configure the load balancer or ingress functionality yourself in order to use either option, and it's going to be rough, sorry.

If you want to go forward with this, you'll have to read through a bunch of documentation to figure out what you want to implement and how to implement it.

https://www.weave.works/blog/kubernetes-faq-how-can-i-route-traffic-for-kubernetes-on-bare-metal

Comment: If you want to go forward with this, you'll have to read through a bunch of documentation to figure out what you want to implement and how to implement it
i know 
can you lead me to a good document

Comment: or explain a bout it
i do not have any idea in baremetal

Comment: Honestly, if you're not able to find the documentation for this yourself, you're in way too deep and should be backing out, not trying to go deeper in.

Comment: can i use ingress and loadbalancer at the same time?

Comment: i read a lot of document . i know i can use metalLB but at the end i  confused about it

Comment: Yes, you can use LB and ingress at the same time. Start building simple and add complexity (metalLB,...) later

Answer (score 2):

According to [`api-server` docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) you can use `--service-node-port-range` parameter for `api-server` or specify it to `kubeadm` configuration when bootstrapping your cluster [see github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/122)

Comment: You are very much on the point. Not directly an answer to the given question tough, but a deployment of ingress controller could also help - it opens ports 80 and 443 by default and with the help of the ingress rule you can achieve the desired behavior.